# Solving Differential equations $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Express in closed form all solution of the following Differential equations
>
> $a)\,\, \dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ and b) $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \sin\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$.

At first sight, it seems like the substitution $\frac{y}{x} = t$ will simplify the D.E's, we get $\int\frac{1+t^2}{1-t-t^2-t^3} dt = $ $\int\frac{dx}{x}$ for 1st D.E and $\int\frac{dt}{\sin{t}-t} =$ $\int\frac{dx}{x}$ for the second. But these integrals seems to be impossible to solve. Is there another way to solve these D.E's or is there a trick to solve the integrals? any hints.

Comment: Will that be considered a closed-form?

Comment: you can keep the integral in the solution

Answer (score 1):

For $b)$ if its equation has the form $\dot{x} = f\left(\frac{x}{t} \right)$ the change of the variable $y = \displaystyle\frac{x}{t}$ results in 
\begin{equation}
\dot{y} =\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x } \dot{x} = -\frac{x}{t^{2}} +\frac{1}{t}\dot{x} = \frac{f(y)- y}{t}.
\end{equation}
This equation is separable.

For $a)$ ... umm I think it's a nonlinear equation and you need to use linearization techniques but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} \rightarrow
(x^2+y^2)\,dy=(x^2-y^2)\,dx $$
$$(x^2-y^2)\,dx-(x^2+y^2)\,dy=0 $$
Let $ M(x,y)=x^2-y^2, $ $N(x,y)=-x^2-y^2. $ If we can find such a function that the condition is met
$$\frac{\partial(tM)}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial(tN)}{\partial x}=0  $$
$$t=t(x,y) $$
 then we will solve the problem